# Women having more than one set of earrings?

Tags: halacha, number, tznius-modesty, jewelry, head

I've heard women can only have one earring (on each ear). Where is the source for this? I know some women who have earrings going up their ear, which is not that tznius, but is it against halacha?

Comment: Why would earrings be un-tznius?

Comment: http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/108867-%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93..

Comment: Tznius is when one calls attention to themselves. Not only with how they dress, also how they act and talk, etc. There are earrings that even one pair attracts attention and there are earrings where two or three do not.

Comment: heard this too, its probably daat yehudit in some communities.

Comment: You probably won’t find a source. You may find a rationale.